# Globally change the value of any string in Angular/Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, string

I'm looking for a solution to change the value of all strings in my application similar to an internationalization/localization.

My strings follow a specific pattern like this:

```
let sample = "[someID]"
```

Then i use the string like this:

```
<h5>Sample:</h5>
<h5>{{sample}}</h5>
```

And the result should look like this:

> Sample:
> Result for the ID

Possible solutions might be to tag the string with some special character similar to the localization in Angular with "$localize", but followed by a custom function to find the correct value for the given ID.

I tried to manipulate primitive string type but as far as I know there is no way to change the default getter for the string type. The only way is to extend the String Prototype by a custom function but then the usage would look like this:

```
<h5>Sample:</h5>
<h5>{{sample.customMethod()}}</h5>
```

This would result in a lot of work because I need to change all currently used string properties in this way.

Maybe there is some sort of way to change the value of the string while it's being compiled or something. Like getting/setting a display value or applying some sort of filter globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a BehaviourSubject in a service? That way you could cast the updated value to all the application via a .next('newValue')

myService.ts:

```
globalSample:BehaviourSubject = new BehaviourSubject<string>('default')
globalSample$ = globalSample.asObservable();

updateSample(newValue:string){
   this.globalSample.next(newValue);
}
```

The sample variable instead of a string would be an Observable and you could use it in the template with an async pipe just like:

component.ts:

```
export class myComponent {
sample:Observable<string> = myService.globalSample$
constructor(myService:MyService){}
}
```

component.html:

```
<h5>Sample:</h5>
<h5>{{sample | async }}</h5>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am wondering if there is any way to read all the string values in a template and manipulate them kind of similar to how the angular locailzer works where you tag all string with '$localize' or mark properties with 'i18n'. Since I am using quite a lot strings plain in the template and not as property.

Comment: You could use a custom pipe to transform the strings in the template according to your needs, is the other way I can think of to achieve your results, actually some translation libraries use that approach

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion. I found out about this by investigating how other translation libraries take on that problem. It's good to get it confirmed here. Thank you for the help.